# Symfony - How can I change the filter title "Filters" in the admin generator?

Tags: symfony1

i would like to know how i change the filters title in the admin generator.
I would like to change "Filters" to another word...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way here is to go to your project's cache, find the autogenerated file '_filters.php'. 
Copy this file to your admin templates dir

```
modules/mymodule/templates/
```

It should be empty if this is a fresh admin module.
edit the ...

```
echo __('filters')
```

to your liking..
This should not affect changes to filters defined in generator.yml going forward